# Encoding accents csv - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, character-encoding

I've been looking through all the answers here and I haven't found the solution.

Here's what I got:

MySQL : 
Database & Table encoding => `utf8_unicode_ci`

I'm trying to convert a an array (containing rows from a query) to CSV

however when i open the csv I get this

```
PrÃ©nom
```

instead of

```
Prénom
```

here's my code

```
$allQueryRows = array();
while($row_query = $stmt_select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $row_query = array_map("utf8_encode", $row_query);
    array_push($allQueryRows, $row_query);
}
download_send_headers("csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
echo array2csv($allQueryRows);
die();


function array2csv(array &$array)
{
   if (count($array) == 0) {
     return null;
   }
   ob_start();
   $df = fopen("php://output", 'w');
   fputcsv($df, array_keys(reset($array)));
   foreach ($array as $row) {
      fputcsv($df, $row);
   }
   fclose($df);
   return ob_get_clean();
}

function download_send_headers($filename) {
    // disable caching
    $now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
    header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
    header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");

    // force download  
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");

    // disposition / encoding on response body
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? - You don't need to read/write a file (virtual or otherwise) for this - you've set the headers, and if they are correct for a CSV file all you'll need to do it output lines to the screen

Comment: Well if your database is already in UTF-8 then your first mistake is this line: `$row_query = array_map("utf8_encode", $row_query);` - `utf8_encode` specifically converts text encoded as ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8. It does **not**, as its name might misleadingly suggest, somehow convert any text into some special UTF-8 form.

Comment: By the way, your `die()` call is useless.

Comment: I added my output which isn't displayed correctly
I removed the array_map("utf8_encode", $row_query); but I'm getting the same output

Answer (score 0):

You should send a `SET NAMES utf8;` MySQL query before your `SELECT` query instead of `array_mapping` your data after.

Then in HTTP headers, send

```
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8;
```

Comment: I added a $db->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
and added the content type to the others but I'm still getting the same output

Answer (score 0):

AT first blush it looks like a utf-16 / utf-8 issue.  Here's how to start to diagnose it:

First, when you say, "however when i open the csv I get this" what do you mean by "open", i.e. open with what?

**I would suggest looking at the file in hex to see exactly what is in the file.**  It could be that what you are opening it in (your editor or whatever) is what is causing the display coming into your eye ball to be wrong OR it could be that the underlying data that your opening program is seeing is wrong.  I think you need to sort out that question first.

(Tip: In general this is the old process of divide and conquer: find a way to test somewhere in the middle of your problem to see which half of your system is causing the problem. The quickest results come from picking test points about half way in the middle of the complexity, not near an edge of the problem, i.e. a Boolean search for the bug. It might not find the problem in the first iteration, but it will help narrow it down.)

Also perhaps you need to tell SQL which to use, e.g. $connection->set_charset("utf8");

Or perhaps what you are seeing is actually being displayed differently from what you think it is because of a utf8/utf16 display level mixup.  I generally set stay with utf8 and so set Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;  (Also if you are viewing this file via your editor make sure it's set to the correct character space.)